# firebase firestore not accepting my write function from swift encoded json

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, format, codable

**this is my struct**

```
 struct CustomerDetail: Codable {
var customerID: String = ""
var firstname: String = ""
var lastname: String = ""
var age: Int = 0
var birthday: Int = 0
var country: String = ""
var pound: Bool = true
var feetboolean: Bool = true
var currentweight: Int = 0
var desiredweight: Int = 0
var sex: Bool = false
var feet: Int = 0
var inches: Int = 0
var cm: Float = 0.0
```

}

**this is my write function**

```
struct writetofirebase {
var customerdetails: CustomerDetail = CustomerDetail()
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var delegate: writefirebase?
func write(){
    print(customerdetails)
    do {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(customerdetails){
            try db.collection("collection name").document("document name").setData(from: data)
            delegate?.didSuccessfulWrite(true)
        }else{
            print("failed to encode")
        }
       
    } catch let error {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error)
    }
}
```

}

**this is my error**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOpQK.png

**this is my firebase structured data**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOpQK.png

Comment: According to the Firestore document (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data), that's not how you append a record to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the data it is receiving inside the `setData` method is not compatible and therefore malformed for the request. You should be updating or setting the data appropriately by defining a custom dictionary or passing the object directly.

```
db.collection("collection name").document("document name").setData(data, merge: true)
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: the mistake i made was not passing the codable struct directly into setData method of the document but using JSONEncoder() to encode the object before passing it into setData(). thanks